# Textbox not shown in listView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, textbox

I'm trying to get a textbox to be shown in a column of listview that also uses GridView.

```
<ListView Margin="30,120,0,0" Name="EquipmentView" SelectionChanged="EquipmentView_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Segui Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="329" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Control" Width="175" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Control}">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ControlBlock}" Width="Auto" /> 
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Setting" Width ="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Setting}">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SettingText}" Width="Auto" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

But when I execute the above, I sit the listview as a grid, but I can't see or edit the textbox. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `DisplayMemberBinding` since you've specified a template for that column (both columns, actually).

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Do you know which eventHandler to use, or how to detect a if something was entered into the textbox? All the tutorials vary in their description and I can't figure out how to get the content of the textboxes.

Comment: Sounds like a different question to me.